# Different Classes but nested classes are same called?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As for training I'm trying to strip some data from a page, but I noticed that "official-store-info info-property-code" and "official-store-info info-property-code" have the same "info" class and when I use find(), it always get the first info instead of the second.

How is this possible and is there any trick to fix this?

Sorry for all the misunderstanding, I'm quite new, so please be aware of spaghetti code.

here's what I tried:

```
<div class="card-description card-phone-description">
        
            
    <input class="profile-info-phone-chk" id="displayMessageSuperior" type="checkbox">
    <label for="displayMessageSuperior" class="ch-btn ch-btn-skin contact-phone show-phone">Ver teléfono</label>
    <span class="profile-info-phones profile-info-phones--multiple">
        
            <span class="profile-info-phone-value">56956558885</span>
        
            <span class="profile-info-phone-value">56956558885</span>
        
    </span>
    
    <div class="official-store-info info-property-code">
        <p class="title">Código</p>
        <p class="info">5550478</p>
    </div>    
    <div class="official-store-info info-property-date">
        <p class="title">Fecha de Publicación</p>
        <p class="info">20-06-2020</p>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
if(pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-code"})):
            no4_text = pageSoup.find('p', {'class':"info"})
            no4 = no4_text.text.strip()
            print (no4)
        else:
            no4 = "N/A"


if(pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-date"})):
            no5_text = pageSoup.find('p', {'class':"info"})
            no5 = no5_text.text.strip()
            print(no5)
        else: 
            no5 = "N/A"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but in each `if..else` block you search the whole `pageSoup` again, which isn't correct. Put the found `<div>` in variable and search within the variable:

```
div = pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-code"})
if div:
    no4_text = div.find('p', {'class':"info"})  # <-- search only within found <div>, not whole pageSoup
    no4 = no4_text.text.strip()
    print (no4)
else:
    no4 = "N/A"


div = pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-date"})
if div:
    no5_text = div.find('p', {'class':"info"})  # <-- search only within found <div>, not whole pageSoup
    no5 = no5_text.text.strip()
    print(no5)
else:
    no5 = "N/A"
```

Prints:

```
5550478
20-06-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pageSoup.findAll()` instead of `pageSoup.find()`, which will return a list. Then you can choose n-th element:

```
findAll('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-date"})[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

congratulations on the first question

You always look in the same soup. You have to distinguish the spoon you want to eat and not always take the whole bowl.

```
spoon = pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-code"})
if(spoon != None):
    no4_text = spoon.find('p', {'class':"info"})
    no4 = no4_text.text.strip()
    print (no4)
else:
    no4 = "N/A"

spoon = pageSoup.find('div', {'class':"official-store-info info-property-date"})
if(spoon != None):
    no5_text = spoon.find('p', {'class':"info"})
    no5 = no5_text.text.strip()
    print(no5)
else: 
    no5 = "N/A"
```